# Не удается округлить элемент с помощью border-radius

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[Ссылка на скачку html и css кода](http://dropmefiles.com/mItu4) [image: введите сюда описание изображения] кнопка к которой применялось border-radius

Comment: [mcve] должен быть **непосредственно** в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте `border-radius` не в процентах, а в пикселях. При задании в процентах идет округление пропорционально ширине и высоте элемента.

Comment: получилось спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

В пикселях задавайте лучше значение `border-radius` и тогда будет нормально всё, заменил на:

```
border-radius: 15px;
```

И всё округлилось нормально.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, получилось )